# How to add "Novalidate" with form in Yii framework. I am using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, yii

This is my code for creating a form:

```
 $form=$this->beginWidget('AForm', array(
        'id'=>'form',
        'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'form-horizontal','name'=>'post-form','ng-controller'=>'FormController','novalidate'),
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    ));
```

result is:

```
<form method="post" action="/post/" id="form" 0="novalidate" ng-controller="FormController" name="post-form" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope">
```

where should i add "novalidate" so that it looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="/post/" id="form" ng-controller="FormController" name="post-form" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope" novalidate>
```

Comment: may be 'novalidate' => 1 would work..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attributes like `disabled` and `disabled="disabled"` are the same so you can do this

```
 'htmlOptions' => array(
       'class'=>'form-horizontal',
       'name'=>'post-form',
       'ng-controller'=>'FormController',
       'novalidate' => 'novalidate', // with full attribute assignment
 ),
```